# python gdb not importing my packages

Tags: python, gdb, kernel

`(gdb) shell ls
Makefile  __init__.py  constants.py.in  cpus.py  dmesg.py  lists.py  modules.py  proc.py  symbols.py  tasks.py  test.py  utils.py  utils.pyc  vmlinux-gdb.py
(gdb)`

I run `python import utils` and I get an ImportError

`ImportError: No module named 'utils'
Error while executing Python code.
(gdb)`

While I can perfectly import utils outside gdb through another python program, it fails when I do it **inside** gdb. What can be the possible issue ? I am running updated version of gdb 7.11 , python is also good.

For some background, if it helps, I was following https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/dev-tools/gdb-kernel-debugging.html , it has a vmlinux python script to help in debugging stuff , where they have written their own packages which they import. But that script is not working because of this fundamental issue.

Thanks

[SOLVED]

Comment: try execute `export PYTHONPATH=currentpath:$PYTHONPATH` before `run` gdb. Good luck.

Comment: OMG That fixed it man !!! Wow. Thank you sir :)

Answer (score 3):

Just extracting the answer by Charles Chao which was in the comment.

Execute following before running gdb:

```
export PYTHONPATH=currentpath:$PYTHONPATH
```